# Sending and Receiving a Email using the gpg encrypt method

Tags: php, gnupg

I want to send and receive the file with encrypted format to others using gpg.  What can I do for this.

Can any one tell me, what I have to do? or give some URL related this. I have read about the following link

http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/encryption.html.en
But I am not able to send the mail to others. Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to send an encrypted e-mail with Evolution (as per URL), or from a PHP script (as per your tags)? I'm a bit confused there...

Comment: @Piskvor: I gess he meant pgp, I'm going to fix this. 
@muruga: By the way, this question is not a programming question, I think you should ask it on superuser.com

Comment: I need to send using PHP

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a good tutorial on doing that at http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265 (first Google hit on "php gpg"); for a PHP library version, see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-encryptsign.php) (the examples at the bottom seem to be what you're after).

Answer (score 0):

kleopatra is a windows gpg encrypting tool, so you can use this if you are using windows. Otherwise, I found the following very useful:

http://www.madboa.com/geek/gpg-quickstart/